# Reverse SSH tunnel works for SSH but not for HTTP

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, http

## What works

I have the following setup:

```
server <-NAT-> VPS <-> client
```

I have set up ssh to my server through a reverse tunnel and the following settings:

- on VPS,

`GatewayPorts yes`

- on server:

`autossh -f -M 57575 -N -R <VPS ip>:9991:localhost:<server ssh port> vps`

With this setup, I can simply `ssh -p 9991 <server user>@<VPS ip>` and log into my server from the client.

## What doesn't

- on VPS,

`GatewayPorts yes`, and otherwise identical setup to SSH case

- on server:

`autossh -f -M 57576 -N -R <VPS ip>:9992:localhost:8988 vps`

`python -m http.server 8988` to start the http server. I can confirm it binds to `0.0.0.0` and I can access it on the local machine.

However, when I try to access the website via `http://<VPS ip>:9992` I get an ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE.

Looking at netstat, the two situations seem identical. On VPS:

`tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9992            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -`

`tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9991            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -`

On server:

`tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8988            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      21003/python`

`tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:<ssh port>           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      550/sshd`

`tcpdump` shows that a connection is established with port 9992 on the VPS, but nothing reaches port 8988 on `server`. The connection is `FIN`ned immediately on the VPS.

Why doesn't this work, when the exactly analogous SSH situation does?

Comment: You should start the server first and then initiate the remote port forwarding. Not the other way round. It also depends what your `http.sever` does (sending empty responses?).

Comment: Well, that was easy. Starting the server first worked. Thanks. I'm curious, though, why does that make a difference? Who keeps the "server started first" state, and how?

Comment: That was the same question I was asking myself when I posted the comment, but unfortunately I don't know the answer yet.

Comment: It must be that SSH checks that the destination port is open when opening the tunnel, and if it's not sets up the empty response failure mode. This seems somewhat strange, but maybe there are security reasons for this.

Comment: Most probably yes. Unfortunately I don't have a time to investigate that further. Good to see that it resolved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start the server first and then initiate the remote port forwarding. Not the other way round.

I am not sure why is that, but obviously it resolves the issue.